# Where can I download EMC's SWAT Switch Analysis Tool

Tags: switch, emc

Do you know where to download EMC's Switch Analysis Tool (SWAT)?

I've followed the instructions in the  "Customer Advisory Letter" I have regarding FLARE upgrade, but the menu options in EMC PowerLink are not there.

The letter states I should find SWAT within Powerlink in "Home > Support > Product and Diagnostic Tools > Environment Analysis Tools > Switch Analysis Tool (SWAT). " - but this menu structure no longer exists, and I've tried searching the site, to no avail.

https://community.emc.com/thread/113532

Many thanks,

Kenny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EMC's support portal Powerlink is exactly where you need to go to get this too. The menu structure below mentioned in the question *does indeed* exist, and is where you need to go to get SWAT:

> "Home > Support > Product and Diagnostic Tools > Environment Analysis Tools > Switch Analysis Tool (SWAT). "

It might be the case that my Powerlink account was not verified / validated with EMC, and EMC support had to take some kind of action to give me access to these menus.. or I was just less familiar with Powerlink. :\

Comment: A lot of vendors are a bit tardy about setting up access.  Cisco - I'm looking at you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean this factitiously but have you tried EMC? They're a pretty approachable lot I find.

Comment: I was given an EMC intranet URL by one EMC employee and an email address to try: "TS_Tools_Support@emc.com" - They have not replied to the email I sent with this query. So I was wondering if anyone on ServerFault knew the URL for downloading this tool.